# Bounded sequence perpendicular to dense subset of $\ell^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Consider the real Banach space $\ell^2$ of square summable sequences and let $\mathcal{A}\subset \ell^2$ be a dense subspace. Suppose I have a bounded sequence $\psi=(\psi_n)_{n\geq 1}\in \ell^\infty$ which has the following property:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \psi_na_n=0$$
for any $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\in \mathcal{A}$. I would like to conclude that $\psi=0$. If I would know that $\psi\in \ell^2$, then this would be easy enough, but unfortunately I only know that $\psi\in\ell^\infty$. Does anyone have a clue how to approach this?

In my specific case I know that each sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ decays exponentially, but I do not know if this useful in this case.

This question is sort of a follow-up question of the following question
[Scaled series of shifted continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066232/scaled-series-of-shifted-continuous-function)
As I stated there, I encountered this problem in my research, where I consider linear differential equations with infinitely many delayed and/or forward terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true.  Consider $\psi = (1,1,1,\ldots)$ with $\mathcal A$ the set of
sequences $a$ of finite support such that $\sum_i a_i = 0$.  To see this is dense in
$l^2$, take any $x \in l^2$ and $\epsilon > 0$.  Take $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n > N} |x_n|^2 < \epsilon^2/2$.  Let $s = \sum_{n \le N} x_n$, and take $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $M \epsilon^2 > 4 |s|^2$.  Let
$$ a_n = \cases{x_n & for $n \le N$\cr
        -s/M & for $N+1 \le n \le N+M$\cr
          0 & otherwise} $$
Then $a \in \mathcal A$ and $\|x - a\| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I understand the statement $a \in \mathcal A$. However, when I try to prove $\Vert x-a \Vert_2^2 < \epsilon^2$, there is a term $2s/M(x_{N+1} + \dots +x_{N+M})$ in excess. It is coming from $(x_n -(-s/M))^2 = x_n^2 + \underbrace{2x_n s/M} +s^2/M^2$ for $N+1 \le n \le N+M$.

Comment: You have $a = b + c$ where $b_n = x_n$ for $n \le N$, $0$ otherwise, while $c_n = -s/M$ for $N+1 \le n \le N+M$, $0$ otherwise.  Then $\|x - a\| \le \|x - b\| + \|c\| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: Thanks Robert. Splitting the stuff in two and remembering that $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ satisfies the triangular inequality as all good old norm is indeed easing the bounding!

Answer (score -2):

Every element of $l^{\infty}$ defines a bounded linear map on $l^2$. If it vanishes on a dense subset it is zero.

Comment: If by this map you mean the map $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\mapsto(a_n\psi_n)_{n\geq 1}$, then I do not see why my condition implies that it would be the zero map on $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: yes I mean that

Comment: No. it's not true that $\ell_\infty\subset\ell_2^*$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I don't understand. $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\rightarrow (a_n\psi_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is linear and $\sum (a_n\psi_n)^2 \le \Vert \psi \Vert_\infty^2 \sum a_n^2$.